# How to install Own Cube on 12.04

Tags: install-from-source

Ok I wanted to install OwnCube (www.owncube.com) on my Ubuntu 32 bit 12.04 desktop. I still have plenty of Ubuntu One space but 5GB for free, I could keep my music there since it streams for free. But I need a little help installing

```
  echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:ownCloud2012/xUbuntu_12.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
  apt-get update
  apt-get install owncloud-client
```

I tried copy/pasting the first line into terminal but cannot be done. Anyone know how I am supposed to do this? I am sure it is simple but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your time and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run these commands as root.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and run these commands one by one.

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:ownCloud2012/xUbuntu_12.04/ /' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install owncloud-client
```

If first command isn't working for you, try do it manually.

Run the following command in terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will open sources.list as root. Paste the following line at the end of it.

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:ownCloud2012/xUbuntu_12.04/ /
```

Then run the last two commands. When asked for varification, press "y" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I get this error after the first line is entered... bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied

Comment: Please try copy, paste, make sure you are copy the complete command. It's working for me.

Comment: Trust me I made sure. I can handle copy + pasting into terminal.

Comment: Well I just opened the software centre and when to software sources, and then added it there. Then I ran the other commands in Terminal.